# Python using While loops to iterate through a 2D list

Tags: python

```
grid = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
cages = [[9, 3, 0, 5, 6], [7, 2, 1, 2], [10, 3, 3, 8, 13], [14, 4, 4, 9, 14, 19], [3, 1, 7], [8, 3, 10, 11, 16], [13, 4, 12, 17, 21, 22], [5, 2, 15, 20], [6, 3, 18, 23, 24]]

noCages = 9
total = 0
i = 0
index = 2
while i < noCages:
   while index < len(i):
      total = total + grid[index/5][index%5]
      print grid[index/5][index%5]
      index += 1
   print total
   i += 1
   total = 0
```

I'm trying to use a while loop to iterate through the cages list and take the 2nd element up to the last element in each of the nested lists. I'm then adding those values to a total, and I want to do that for all of the nested lists. I'm having trouble using the while loop to iterate over the cages list. How can I better implement this. (also it says len(i) is an int and has no length, which makes sense. However, I didn't know how to work with it.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Not sure whether you're using Python 2 or 3, but in Python 3 you can't use [index/5] as a list index, as that will return a float. If you're trying to get the sum of cages[0][1 to 4] you can use sum(cages[0][1:5]). Using the sum function you can add up whatever slice of the list you want without iterating them.

Comment: Why a `while` loop? Doesn't `for` make much better sense for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `for` loop, you will get one list at a time out of your nested list (`for cage in cages`), you can then use another for to read individual values. the `[1:]` says to skip the first element.

```
total = 0
for cage in cages:
    for value in cage[1:]:
        total += value
print(total)
```